# VB.NET Dynamically created Label does not have Label properties

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, label

The following code snippet is giving compilation error in a VB.Net module:

```
Dim ph1 As Placeholder = Page.FindControl("The PlaceHolder")
Dim lbl As New Label
lbl.ID = "theID"
lbl.Text = "The text"
ph1.Controls.Add(lbl)
```

The compilation errors are:

'ID' is not a member of 'Label'

'Text' is not a member of 'Label'

Value of type 'Label' cannot be converted to 'Control'

Comment: ID isn't a member of a label. As for the other issues, it feels like you're referring to another type of Label, and not the Windows.Forms.Label. Is it possible some references are mixed up?

Comment: I should have said, this is a ASP application, so Windows.Forms is not applicable. It seems like references are messed up, because this code was actually working.

Comment: It is almost certainly the case that `Label` in your code is not referring to `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label` but rather some other `Label` class. Click on the type name and press the F1 key to be taken to the documentation for that type. What type is it? That's assuming that it's a first-party type. If no documentation opens, right-click and go the definition, as it might be something in your project.

Comment: Thank you. I checked out the project again and reapplied my changes and it worked, so something in the solution/project settings must have (inadvertently) changed.